# Comparison of 2 fans

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, electronics, electrical-engineering, fan

I have 2 20" box fans. The first fan draws .65 Amp and claims 1780 CFM. The second fan draws .45 Amp and claims 2300 CFM. The fans are new, and the electric motors are of similar design, so I think it is safe to assume that the first fan puts more power into the fan blades. There is quite a difference in the design of the fan blades. Is it POSSIBLE that the blade design difference could account for a 30% greater air flow while drawing 35% less power. If this is theoretically possible, then where does all that extra energy go. The only place I can think of is into heating the air.

Comment: Could the weight of the blades be significantly different? Would be cool if you included a photo of them

Comment: Once the fans are up to speed , there is no further acceleration so the weight of the blades should be irrelevent, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor design of the blade shape will cause more useless churning of the air and greater noise generation. Better design will cause less churn, less noise, and better power transfer from the motor to the air.

The difference shows up in the amount of heat that winds up in the air. More churn and noise means more heating of the air.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As soon as I read "churn" I could picture what was happening.